# spring integeration amqp when convert message from amqp occur err, it does not go retry

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-rabbit, spring-integration-amqp

spring integeration amqp version: 5.0.11

goal: when occur fatal exceptions, message will drop. but not fatal, messages will requeue and go retry policy.

but in my case, i have a custom message converter,  when my convert occur some non-fatal err, it will requeue always and never go to the retry policy.

i try to read code, `AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.Listener#onMessage` when before retry, it convert message, it means that when message convert occur some err, it does not go to retry,  will go error handler.

```
public void onMessage(final Message message, final Channel channel) throws Exception {
        boolean retryDisabled = AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.this.retryTemplate == null;
        try {
            if (retryDisabled) {
                createAndSend(message, channel);
            }
            else {
                 final org.springframework.messaging.Message<Object> toSend = createMessage(message, channel); 
                AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.this.retryTemplate.execute(context -> {
                            StaticMessageHeaderAccessor.getDeliveryAttempt(toSend).incrementAndGet();
                            setAttributesIfNecessary(message, toSend);
                            sendMessage(toSend);
                            return null;
                        },
                        (RecoveryCallback<Object>) AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.this.recoveryCallback);
            }
        }
```

my code below:

```
  @Bean
public IntegrationFlow EndpointMessageAndConvertModelDlxFlow(
    @Qualifier("rabbitmqUnFatalExceptionRetryTemplate") RetryTemplate template,
    ConnectionFactory factory,
    EndpointCodeDelegatingMessageConverter converter) {
    final MailRabbitmqProperties.Queue queue = getQueueConfig(ENDPOINT_BUFFER_DLX_NODE,
        ENDPOINT_BUFFER_FUNCTION);
    template.setRetryPolicy(endpointMessageExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy()); //fatal err not go retry
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(factory, queue.getName())
        .configureContainer(smlc -> {
            smlc.acknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO); //
            smlc.defaultRequeueRejected(true); //requeue
            final ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler errorHandler =
                new ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler(
                    new EndPointMessageFatalExceptionStrategy());
            smlc.errorHandler(errorHandler);
        })
        .retryTemplate(template) 
        .messageConverter(converter))
        .channel(mailActionCreateTopicChannel())
        .get();
}
```

how can i resolve this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we believe that converter error is really *fatal*. That's why the conversion from AMQP message is really done outside of the retry loop.

If you are sure that error in your converter is intermittent, consider to include a retry logic into your converter, so when an `AmqpInboundChannelAdapter` calls `this.converter.fromMessage(message)`, your `RetryTemplate` is going to be applied if an exception occurs.

See `ProxyFactoryBean` and `RetryInterceptorBuilder` if you use one of the out-of-the-box converters. Otherwise a `@Retryable` can be applied to the `convert()` method.

See more info in the Spring Retry project: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/retry.html